# Visual Studio Installer Project prevent prerequisites from automatically rebooting

Tags: visual-studio

We have an installer built with Visual Studio Installer Project. Occasionally running it will cause the computer to reboot with no prompt or warning. It appears that if it detects Windows needs to reboot to install a prerequisite, it will just go ahead and do that.

The installer can then be run again to completion this time, but we would prefer not to surprise and tick off users like this, is there a configuration to prompt the necessary reboot instead?